# Using final variable in lambda expression Java

Tags: java, final, completable-future

I have an app that fetches a lot of data, so I would like to paginate the data into chunks and process those chunks individually rather than dealing with the data all at once. So I wrote a function I am calling every n seconds to check if a chunk is done and then process that chunk. My problem is I have no way of keeping track of the fact that I just processed a chunk and that I should move onto the next chunk when it is available. I was thinking something along the lines of the code below, however I cannot call `multiplier++;` as it complains that it is not behaving like a final variable anymore. I would like to use something like multiplier so that once the code processes a chunk it 1) doesn't process the same chunk again and 2) moves onto the next chunk. Is it possible to do this? Is there a modifier one can put on multiplier to help avoid race conditions?

```
int multiplier = 1;
CompletableFuture<String> completionFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

final ScheduledFuture<?> checkFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // parse json response
    String response = getJSONResponse();
    JsonObject jsonObject = ConverterUtils.parseJson(response, true)
      .getAsJsonObject();

    int pages = jsonObject.get("stats").getAsJsonObject().get("pages").getAsInt();

    // if we have a chunk of n pages records then process them with dataHandler function
    if (pages > multiplier * bucketSize) {
        dataHandler.apply(getResponsePaginated((multiplier - 1) * bucketSize, bucketSize));
        multiplier++;
    }
    if (jsonObject.has("finishedAt") && !jsonObject.get("finishedAt").isJsonNull()) {
        // we are done!
        completionFuture.complete("");
    }

}, 0, sleep, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: you can try using static variable and synchronize the update of counter.

Comment: A lambda like that defeats the purpose of lambdas to me. The best lambdas are one liners or close to that. You could move that code into a method and reference the method instead. That will greatly improve your code readability. Something like executor.scheduleAtFixedRat(SomeClass::someMethod). To answer your question, you may want to make your variable a static or an instance variable. Local variables used in lambdas are effectively final.

Comment: @ivange94 Are you saying if it's not a lambda I don't have these restrictions? I can just pass in a predefined function instead?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. I was just making a personal opinion about on your code. Sorry. The accepted answer seems to be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Since this is a mutable type, you can assign it to a `final` variable while still being able to change its value. This also addresses the synchronization issue between the callbacks:

```
final AtomicInteger multiplier = new AtomicInteger(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
  //...
  multiplier.incrementAndGet();
}, 0, sleep, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```